# Dividing two columns in a file and printing the output in new column to the same file for multiple files

Tags: python, perl, numpy, awk

I have a number of files which is in VCF format.That is how it looks like

```
1   127573  rs7 G   A   79.78   .   AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.231;ClippingRankSum=-0.358;DB;DP=5;FS=3.979;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=0.358;QD=15.96;ReadPosRankSum=1.231  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:2,3:5:27:108,0,27
```

In which i need to divide the second part of last column and and print the output in new column.. ie, from the above example, its 3 and 5 ( from 10th column 0/1:2,3:5:27:108,0,27) and the output it should look like, That is with 0.6 (ie 3/5) as last column

```
 1  127573  rs7 G   A   79.78   .   AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.231;ClippingRankSum=-0.358;DB;DP=5;FS=3.979;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=0.358;QD=15.96;ReadPosRankSum=1.231  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:2,3:5:27:108,0,27 0.6
```

In order to achieve this I used awk in unix, as follows,

```
cat result_1 |cut -f10 | sed 's/:/\t/g' >sample
cat sample | cut -f2 | sed 's/,/\t/g' | awk '$2!=0 || $3!=0{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$2/$3}' >result_1
```

But it complains as

```
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

any other alternative solutions in Python or Perl would be great..!!!

Comment: If $2 is non-zero your awk action will execute regardless of whether or not $3 is zero so if it is then you'll get a divide by zero from `$2/$3`. It's your logic that's the problem, not the tool you're using.Of course, you don;t actually need the temp file and pipes, cats, cuts, and sed since awk can do everything you need itself in one command. If you simplify your example a bit I'm sure someone will take a look at it - right now the input line is just too long and full of too much irrelevant detail for many people to want to bother trying to understand it.

Comment: could please suggest an alternate solution ..with awk

Comment: Sure, just do what I asked and edit your question to use briefer simpler input/output that demonstrates your problem first. I see no reason why we need to try to understand an example that contains about 20 fields, some with their own 10+ fields - make it, say, 5 fields, and within each, say, 3 sub-fields. Also - idk if the input you show is the contents of "result_1" or of "sample" - make sure you show us "result_1" as "sample" is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{split($NF, a, /[,:]/); $(++NF) = a[3]/a[4]; print}' file
```

OK, division by zero:

```
awk '{split($NF, a, /[,:]/); $(++NF) = (a[4]==0 ? "Inf" : a[3]/a[4]); print}' file
```

Comment: That will alter the whitespace between fields.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: The script give sthe same error it was giving before..awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=BM_CR_pat_4.vep FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one perl way of doing it:

```
perl -ne 'chomp;if(/\t[^, ]+,(\d+):0*([1-9]\d*)[\S ]*$/){$n=$1;$d=$2;print("$_\t",$n/$d,"\n")}else{print("$_\t\n")}' < result_1 > result_1.new
```

This will do it. It will ensure a non-0 positive value for the denominator in the match ([1-9]\d*), and allows for leading zeros with the '0*' in front of it.

The chomp removes the hard return ("\n"), so it's tacked on in the print.

It ensures you're parsing the last column from the last tab to the end of the string and it allows spaces.

The -n wraps the code in while(){...}.

It adds a tab even if there would have been a division by zero but in that case, leaves the last column empty.

You can mv the file afterward if you want to overwrite the original, but I prefer to save precursors as a backup.

There probably exists a more succinct/readable way of doing it in perl or via another language, but this suffices.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this Perl one liner doesnt  change anything in result_1.new file

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. When I use it on the example you gave, it adds a column at the end with the value 0.6. Perhaps you have other data whose last column is formatted differently? This solution requires the last column to have a comma, number, colon, and another number (first occurrence of that sequence) and then non-white space and spaces to the end of the line. Trailing tabs will defeat this solution. Any of that can be accounted for, but I would have to see all possibilities. If it doesn't work on the example, I'd have to see your attempt to figure out what was different.